# Ошибка при отправке JSON на API методом POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api, post

Python только начал изучать, по этому сильно не критикуйте.
Имеется скрипт отправки данных в API:

```
import requests
import json

AUTHURL = 'https://<здесь мой логин>.amocrm.ru/private/api/auth.php'
TESTURL = 'https://<здесь мой логин>.amocrm.ru/api/v2/account?with=pipelines,groups,note_types,task_types'
FORMURL = 'https://<здесь мой логин>.amocrm.ru/api/v2/incoming_leads/form'
CONTACTURL = 'https://<здесь мой логин>.amocrm.ru/api/v2/contacts'
LEADS = 'https://<здесь мой логин>.amocrm.ru/api/v2/leads'
AUTHDATA = {'USER_HASH': '<здесь мой ключ API>', 'USER_LOGIN': '<здесь мой логин>'}
POSTPARAMS = {'api_key': '<здесь мой ключ API>', 'login': '<здесь мой логин>'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

JSONFORMDATA = {

"add": [
    {
        "source_name": "WEB сайт",
        "source_uid": "a1fee7c0fc436088e64ba2e8822ba2b3",
        "created_at": "1529007000",
        "incoming_entities": {
            "leads": [
                {
                    "name": "Покупка"
                }
            ],
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "name": "Федя",
                    "responsible_user_id": "1903006",
                    "custom_fields": [
                        {
                            "id": "382707",
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": "+77777777777",
                                    "enum": "WORK"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "389993",
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": "sfgh3gh233h3h3h3"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "389995",
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": "Обратный звонок"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "incoming_lead_info": {
            "form_id": "329248",
            "form_page": "vdtest.ru",
            "ip": "127.0.0.1",
            "service_code": "QkKwSam8"
        }
    }
]

}

CONTACTDATA = {"add": [{"name": "Тест"}]}

LEADSDATA = {
"add": [{"name": "Тест", "custom_fields": [{"id": 385885, "values": [{"value": "web"}]}]}]}

# Инициализируем сессию
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url=AUTHURL)
# print('Инициализация сессии:')
# print(session.cookies.get_dict())
# print(response.status_code)

# Автроизация и проверка cookie
authorisation = session.post(url=AUTHURL, params=AUTHDATA)
# print('Авторизация и проверка сессии:')
# print(session.cookies.get_dict())
# print(authorisation.status_code)

# Выполняем тестовый запрос
getuserdata = session.get(url=TESTURL, params=POSTPARAMS)
# testdata = getuserdata.json()
# print('Тестовый запрос данных учётной записи:')
# print(testdata)
# print(getuserdata.status_code)

# Отправка формы
formpostdata = session.post(url=FORMURL, params=POSTPARAMS, json=JSONFORMDATA, headers=headers)

# print(formpostdata.status_code, formpostdata.reason)

# print('Дополнительная проверка сессии:')
# print(session.cookies.get_dict())

formpostdataj = formpostdata.json()
print('Ответ от API:')
print(formpostdataj)

contactsend = session.post(url=CONTACTURL, params=POSTPARAMS, json=CONTACTDATA, headers=headers)
formpostdatac = contactsend.json()
print(formpostdatac)

leadssend = session.post(url=LEADS, params=POSTPARAMS, json=LEADSDATA, headers=headers)
formpostdatal = leadssend.json()
print(formpostdatal)
```

`JSON` данные `JSONFORMDATA` не уходят, API возвращает ошибку 400. Грешил на саму API. НО проверил потом отправку других данных CONTACTDATA и LEADSDATA, API принимает. Попробовал отправку JSON данные JSONFORMDATA через `PHP`, API запрос принял и успешно обработал.

Вот никак не могу разобраться где у меня ошибка, массив JSONFORMDATA копирую из конструктора API, так же как и CONTACTDATA и LEADSDATA.

Думаю проблема в `Python`, может я что то не так делаю?

Вот ответы от API:

```
{'status': 'fail', 'error': 'Invalid data', 'error_code': 400, '_links': {'self': {'href': '/api/v2/incoming_leads/form?api_key=<здесь мой код API>&login=<здесь мой логин>', 'method': 'post'}}}
{'_links': {'self': {'href': '/api/v2/contacts', 'method': 'post'}}, '_embedded': {'items': [{'id': 12715121, 'request_id': 0, '_links': {'self': {'href': '/api/v2/contacts?id=12715121', 'method': 'get'}}}]}}
{'_links': {'self': {'href': '/api/v2/leads', 'method': 'post'}}, '_embedded': {'items': [{'id': 4844053, 'request_id': 0, '_links': {'self': {'href': '/api/v2/leads?id=4844053', 'method': 'get'}}}]}}
```

Comment: Проблема решена [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843746/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-json-%D0%B2-url-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82). Издержки особенности работы методов API.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше предположение о том что API не принимает JSON неверно:

```
requests.post(url, json=JSONFORMDATA)
```