# Преобразование JSON в URL текст

Tags: python, json, post, api, urlencode

В поисках решения [вот этой проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842238/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-api-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-post) выяснил, что проблема в API, оно принимает не JSON, а в отправляемых данных должен быть URL text. Вопрос такой, можно ли преобразовать такой JSON:

```
JSONFORMDATA = {

"add": [
{
    "source_name": "WEB сайт",
    "source_uid": "a1fee7c0fc436088e64ba2e8822ba2b3",
    "created_at": "1529007000",
    "incoming_entities": {
        "leads": [
            {
                "name": "Покупка"
            }
        ],
        "contacts": [
            {
                "name": "Федя",
                "responsible_user_id": "1903006",
                "custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "id": "382707",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "+77777777777",
                                "enum": "WORK"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "389993",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "sfgh3gh233h3h3h3"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "389995",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "Обратный звонок"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "incoming_lead_info": {
        "form_id": "329248",
        "form_page": "vdtest.ru",
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "service_code": "QkKwSam8"
    }
}
]

}
```

в такой формат:

```
add[0][source_name]=WEB FORM
&add[0][source_uid]=wb0123456789
&add[0][created_at]=1529105760
&add[0][incoming_entities][leads][0][name]=WEB Bay
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][name]=John
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][responsible_user_id]=2473552
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][id]=382707
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][value]=+792887776655
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][enum]=MOB
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][id]=389993
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]=cid123456789
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][id]=389995
&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][values][0][value]=Product
&add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_id]=329248
&add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_page]=localhost
&add[0][incoming_lead_info][ip]=127.0.0.1
&add[0][incoming_lead_info][service_code]=myformmw
```

Это декодированные данные из URL text, которые принимает API:

```
add%5B0%5D%5Bsource_name%5D=WEB+FORM&add%5B0%5D%5Bsource_uid%5D=wb0123456789&add%5B0%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=1529105760&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bleads%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=WEB+Bay&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=John&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bresponsible_user_id%5D=2473552&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=382707&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%2B792887776655&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Benum%5D=MOB&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=389993&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=cid123456789&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=389995&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_entities%5D%5Bcontacts%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcustom_fields%5D%5B2%5D%5Bvalues%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=Product&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_lead_info%5D%5Bform_id%5D=329248&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_lead_info%5D%5Bform_page%5D=localhost&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_lead_info%5D%5Bip%5D=127.0.0.1&add%5B0%5D%5Bincoming_lead_info%5D%5Bservice_code%5D=myformmw
```

Как выяснилось, в примере PHP не используют чистый JSON, а строят массив. Может в Python тоже необходимо построить подобный массив или есть способ проще, ведь на сколько я понимаю, как таковых массивов в Python нет.

Comment: Интересная задачка у вас :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно, рекурсию не очень люблю, но в таких задачах она себя хорошо показывает:

Данные (из вопроса):

```
JSON_FORM_DATA = {
    "add": [
        ...
}
```

[Код:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f4e1921717fb2e40ecd666cc0be1733bc2c75797/dict_to_url_params.py)

```
def dict_to_url_params(json_data, root):
    def deep(node, root, items):
        if isinstance(node, list):
            for i, value in enumerate(node):
                node_root = root + f'[{i}]'
                deep(value, node_root, items)

        elif isinstance(node, dict):
            for key, value in node.items():
                node_root = root + f'[{key}]'
                deep(value, node_root, items)

        else:
            root += '=' + node
            items.append(root)

    items = []

    deep(json_data, root, items)

    return items
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = dict_to_url_params(JSON_FORM_DATA['add'], root='add')
    
    params = '&'.join(items)
    print('Params: ' + params)
    print()
    
    print('Params:')
    for x in items:
        print(x)
```

Результат:

```
Params: add[0][source_name]=WEB сайт&add[0][source_uid]=a1fee7c0fc436088e64ba2e8822ba2b3&add[0][created_at]=1529007000&add[0][incoming_entities][leads][0][name]=Покупка&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][name]=Федя&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][responsible_user_id]=1903006&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][id]=382707&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][value]=+77777777777&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][enum]=WORK&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][id]=389993&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]=sfgh3gh233h3h3h3&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][id]=389995&add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][values][0][value]=Обратный звонок&add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_id]=329248&add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_page]=vdtest.ru&add[0][incoming_lead_info][ip]=127.0.0.1&add[0][incoming_lead_info][service_code]=QkKwSam8

Params:
add[0][source_name]=WEB сайт
add[0][source_uid]=a1fee7c0fc436088e64ba2e8822ba2b3
add[0][created_at]=1529007000
add[0][incoming_entities][leads][0][name]=Покупка
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][name]=Федя
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][responsible_user_id]=1903006
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][id]=382707
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][value]=+77777777777
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][enum]=WORK
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][id]=389993
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]=sfgh3gh233h3h3h3
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][id]=389995
add[0][incoming_entities][contacts][0][custom_fields][2][values][0][value]=Обратный звонок
add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_id]=329248
add[0][incoming_lead_info][form_page]=vdtest.ru
add[0][incoming_lead_info][ip]=127.0.0.1
add[0][incoming_lead_info][service_code]=QkKwSam8
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А можно как нибудь упорядочить вывод? Т.е. чтобы согласно исходного JSON строился массив, а не каждый раз вразброс?

Comment: @MasterWenom, дело в том, что JSON_FORM_DATA состоит из словарей, а у них порядок ключей не гарантирован. Правда тут есть выход -- [использовать OrderedDict](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4516206d6e29608a732b7c096cd557b11c7ce67b/telegram_bot__image_process_bot/commands.py#L69) тогда вручную без литерала придется заполнить. Или попробовать на новых версиях питона запустить, читал где-то что разработчики смогли словарям сохранить порядок практически без потери в производительности. А у вас, кст, питон какой версии стоит?

Comment: @MasterWenom, кст, а разве важен порядок параметров в url? Там ведь тоже как ключ-значение они описаны

Comment: да я тупанул на счёт порядка, в url параметров он не важен. Всё ок. Версия Python 3.6